# Is it possible to get the number of decimals for an SPL token in an anchor program?

Tags: anchor-spl

I want to use the transfer checked instruction to transfer fungible tokens. The problem is that I do not know the number of decimals that a token might have.

Is it possible to find out the number of decimals a token has in an anchor program?

```
use anchor_spl::token::{
      TransferChecked,
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Imagine you have a mint x:

`pub mint_x: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>`

You can get the decimals by reading the following parameter:

```
mint_x.decimals
```